# Iterative postback on triggering Events using javascript doPostBack

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am facing problem with iterative function call while trying to trigger a serverside  postback for a textbox using javascript, which also registered with bootstrap datetimepicker.

Please find the below mentioned snippet being used, kindly point out if i am doing something wrong.

Asp.net

```
<custom:DtPicker runat="server" ID="fdtTest" DateFormats="ddMMyyyy" OnSelectedDateChanged="fdtTest_SelectedDateChanged" />

protected void fdtTest_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
  fnControlRendercphMain_fdtTest1();                      Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler_cphMain_fdtTest1);
});

function fnControlRendercphMain_fdtTest1() 
{
/*Textbox Blur starts here*/
     $('#cphMain_fdtTest').blur(function (e)
       {              $('#cphMain_fdtTest_hfDtp').val(moment($('#cphMain_fdtTest').datetimepicker('getDate')).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
   setTimeout(function () { __doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$fdtTest', "OnChange"); }, 30);});
     /*Textbox Blur Ends here*/
      $('#cphMain_fdtTest').datetimepicker(
      { 
        defaultDate: moment('23/09/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), useCurrent:          false, format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' 
       });
    } function EndRequestHandler_cphMain_fdtTest1(sender, args) {
fnControlRendercphMain_fdtTest1();}
```

Comment: In `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(fn)` requires `ScriptManager`

Comment: ScriptManager was included on the  page and even i was not gettting error instead the control event was recursively iterating on postback ; The problem seems to be with the below mentioned block  $('#cphMain_fdtTest').blur(function (e){ });  getting registered on EndRequestHandler.  I have removed rest of the code from endrequest handler and just registered the plugin.  Still searching for exact cause..